# How to parse string in which xml. Android

Tags: java, android, string, xml-parsing

How can I get the data that I need from an xml string?
This is my string

```
String a="<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
            "<answer>\n" +
            "\t<name>Винт DIN 965 М4*16(2000 шт)</name>\n" +
            "\t<balance>Отсутствует</balance>\n" +
            "\t<code>00-00000029</code>\n" +
            "</answer>"
```

How i can get `<name>,<balance>,<code>` in different variables?
I can get all answer in one string `(String b="
    Винт DIN 965 М4*16(2000 шт)
    Отсутствует
    00-00000029
")`, but i need get in differentr string `String one="Винт DIN 965 М4*16(2000 шт)" String two ="Отсутствует", String thr="00-00000029".`
Sorry for my English)

This code i tried

```
DocumentBuilder newDocumentBuilder = null;
                try {
                    newDocumentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
                } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Document parse = null;
                try {
                    parse = newDocumentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(answer)));
                } catch (SAXException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }Винт DIN 965 М4*16(2000 шт)
    Отсутствует
    00-00000029`enter code here`
System.out.print(parse.getFirstChild().getTextContent();)  // Винт DIN 965 М4*16(2000 шт) Отсутствует 00-00000029
```

Comment: It seems you are using XML standard format in your string, so you can use any XML parser in android like Gson for JSON in android.
if yes let me know to show how to do that

Comment: Yes, its standart format

Comment: Oh, i find answer for me!

Comment: Of course, you can find it easily for XML standard format

Answer (score 0):

Its answer for my question

```
                                        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                                        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
                                        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(ss));

                                        Document doc = (Document) xpath.evaluate("/", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
                                        postName = xpath.evaluate("/answer/name", doc);
                                        postBalance = xpath.evaluate("/answer/balance", doc);
                                        String bal = xpath.evaluate("/answer/code", doc);
                                        tvPost.setText(postName);
                                        tvPostBalance.setText(postBalance);

                                    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```